# In python, How does the count() function specifies the count?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I got a code for machine learning from pytorch tutorial.

I understood most of the code, but some part of code is unclear to me.

That code is very simple as following

```
for t in count():
   # do something
```

This is very simple for loop. But I don't understand about count() function. There is no one specifies count() how man number it should count.

I just type that simple for loop with print(t) inside the loop in python command line, then it just print the number t as increasing from 0 to maybe the infinite number of int.

so, what I want to know is how that count() function specifies the count.

Comment: Almost certainly, you have an import like `from itertools import *` or `from itertools import count`. In which case, this is simply `itertools.count`, which is an infinite iterator. So yes, unless you break out of it, it won't stop until you kill the Python process or the `int` objects increasingly take up more and more memory and your system crashes (would be cool to see how long that takes...)

Comment: Have you checked itertools.count? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=count#itertools.count

Comment: I finally understood from your comment!!! Thank you very much!!